# Query to Exlude results

Tags: sql

I have the following request and I'm not sure how to achieve it SQL.
Let's say we have three tables Contacts, Subscription and Products.
Let me edit the information and add more context.

We have the following structure:
The user buys a Subscription, the Subscription contains a Product.
We have two types of Products Trial and Monthly.
Users can buy a trial product, and after that, he can decide to buy a monthly one.
Our Marketing Team wants to have a results of all users who have Trial subscriptions (let's say we have 5 people), but also if any of these 5 people bought a Monthly Subscription to Exclude it from the results because we don't want to send him promotional emails since he bought a license.

This how currently SQL looks likes:

```
select cs_subscription.cs_contactyominame as 'Contact Name',
product.name as 'Product Name',
cs_subscription.createdon as 'Created On',
cs_subscription.cs_expirationdate as 'Expiration Date',
case
when cs_subscription.cs_status=110000000 then 'Active'
end as 'Status'
from cs_subscription
join product on cs_subscription.cs_product=product.productid
where product.name='Trial'
and cs_status=110000000
and cs_contactyominame IS NOT NULL
and name IS NOT NULL
order by cs_expirationdate asc
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syigH.png)

One of the Users in the results - Mebi Fo has also Monthly Subscription, so we want it out of the results so he doesn't receive any Trial emails.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR2oE.png)

THe second screenshot is from our internal system that stores the subscription details for every user.

I hope I explained the scenario well enough? Any ideas on how should I achieve that?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) Simplify, perhaps 3 people instead of 10. ([mcve])

Comment: What is your DBMS? Oracle? MySQL? SQL Server? ... Please tag your request with the DBMS in question.

Comment: `select contact.name `, where the contact come from?

Comment: In your current query, you are showing the product. But as you are looking for contacts who subscribed to product A, but not for product B, you already know what products this is about and I suppose it suffices to show only the contact without the product in your results?

Comment: On a side note: Single quotes are for string literals, not for names. This is correct: `where product.name = 'Yellow T-Shirt'` and this is not: `product.name as 'Product'`. The standard delimiter for names is the double quote `"`, but some DBMS use some other propriatry delimiter instead.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are looking for contacts that subscribed for yeallow t-shirt but not for orange t-shirt you may use `in` and `not in`

```
select contact.name
from contact
where contact.contactid in (
  select s.contact
  from subscriptions s
  join product p on s.product = p.productid
  where p.name = 'Yellow T-Shirt'
) and contact.contactid not in (
  select s.contact
  from subscriptions s
  join product p on s.product = p.productid
  where p.name = 'Orange T-Shirt'
)
```

The solution assume that you never have null value in `subscriptions.contact`, (i.e. not null foreign key).

Answer (score 0):

```
select
       contact.name
from contact
join subscriptions on subscriptions.contact = contactid
join product on subscriptions.product = product.productid
group by contact.name
having MAX(product.name) = 'Yellow T-Shirt'
       AND MIN(product.name) = 'Yellow T-Shirt'
```

The above query will join all products with a subscription. and then group them by the contract name. Since you translate nvarchar as int and use MIN and MAX to get a single value. So only products that have 'yellow T-Shirt' will be selected.

Comment: `CAST('Yellow T-Shirt' AS INT)`? Should raise an error.

Comment: I'd add `where product.name in ( 'Yellow T-Shirt', 'Orange T-Shirt')` to avoid problems with blue and white t-shirts, and socks and trousers. (And speed up the query, if proper index are available.)